# PowerBI - Graphical representation DateTime for room booking

Tags: sql-server, datetime, powerbi, reporting, powerbi-desktop

I have SQL table with datetime information of room booking

[image: room booking table]

and I need show graphical representation this data in PowerBI for example as this:

[image: graphical representation of bookings]

Is it possible and how? If not what I can use to get similar results?

Thank you for all answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Deneb custom visual for this (certified and free):

[image]

https://vega.github.io/vega-lite/examples/bar_gantt.html

https://deneb-viz.github.io/

Comment: Great, it's looking fine, but I need solve this without any 3rd party components.

Comment: There are hacks using stacked bar charts but they are just hacks with lots of drawbacks. Deneb is certified so completely safe and free to use.